# Sequelize TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

In Sequelize limit inside both condition not working

```js
sampleTable.findAll({
   ...,
   limit:5,
   include:[
      ..,
      limit:5
   ]
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Keywords in sequelize are case-sensitive. 
replace **Limit** with **limit** and it should work.

example:

```
const data = await someModel.findAll({
  attributes: ['id'],
  where: {
    id: payload.someId
  },
  limit: payload.limit
});
```

Comment: No check with include limit condition also and let me know

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this error was to add foreignKey(sampleTable_id) in attributes of a Model you include.

Answer (score 0):

Dmitry's answer worked for me, you should add the foreign key in the attributes array of the included Model to get rid of this error.
sequelize version 4.44.4

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30659261)